# how to add an extra term into a objective function in Pyomo?

Tags: pyomo

I have two objectives functions,but the difference between both objectives functions is the last term

```
def objective_function(model):
    return (sum(model.costos_Gas[v] * model.HR_Gas[v] * model.PT_Gas[t,v] * (model.DeltaT*(1/3600000)) \
                           for v in model.T_gas for t in model.periodos)                   
                         + sum(model.costos_Car[c] * model.HR_Car[c] * model.PT_Car[t,c] * (model.DeltaT*(1/3600000)) \
                               for c in model.T_car for t in model.periodos))

model.obj1 = z.Objective(rule=objective_function, sense = z.minimize, doc='Función objetivo en dolares $')
```

the other

```
def objective_function1(model):
    return (sum(model.costos_Gas[v] * model.HR_Gas[v] * model.PT_Gas[t,v] * (model.DeltaT*(1/3600000)) \
                           for v in model.T_gas for t in model.periodos)                   
                         + sum(model.costos_Car[c] * model.HR_Car[c] * model.PT_Car[t,c] * (model.DeltaT*(1/3600000)) \
                               for c in model.T_car for t in model.periodos)) +  (model.Lagrang[ t ] fot t in list_lag)

model.obj2 = z.Objective(rule=objective_function1, sense = z.minimize, doc='Función objetivo en dolares $')
```

the problem appears when I try to add an extra term to the objective function ,  it seems like the model doesn't recognize it.
the questions is How can I add an extra term in the objective function without creating another objective function for example ?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to add a term to your objective function after it was initially created, or do you mean that your second code paragraph doesn't work? And what is the description of the error?

Comment: yeah when I add that term the code doesn't work ,  I've tried with set_value() but it doesn't work too

Comment: It would be very helpful if you provided the name of the error. Otherwise, we can't assume what is your problem. Every question poster on SO has a code that "doesn't work". Since we can't really run your code, we can't guess the error code just by looking at your post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set_value()` on the objective:

```
>>> from pyomo.environ import *
>>> m = ConcreteModel()
>>> m.x = Var()
>>> m.o = Objective(expr=m.x)
>>> m.o.pprint()
o : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
    Key  : Active : Sense    : Expression
    None :   True : minimize :          x
>>> m.o.set_value(expr=m.x + 1)
>>> m.o.pprint()
o : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
    Key  : Active : Sense    : Expression
    None :   True : minimize : x + 1
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but if you wana add an more complex expression how could I do it ? for example I've tried to use model.obj.add but it doesn't work too

Comment: If you have a complex expression `m.e`, `m.o.set_value(expr=m.o.expr + m.e)`

Comment: for example, if the objective function is within a loop then it will always add up the term in this case m.e, I have a loop and then I need add m.e into the objective function but in every iteration m.e must to change and remove the previous m.e added in the previous iteration how can I do that ?

Comment: `m.base_expr = m.x1 + 2 * m.x2`, `m.changing_expr = m.x1 * m.x2`, `m.o.set_value(expr=m.base_expr + m.changing_expr)`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you can modify the model's objective function directly in an intuitive way, simply by adding to it. For example, let's say that you have this model:

```py
import pyomo.environ as pyo
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.x = pyo.Var()
model.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=model.x, sense=pyo.minimize)
```

and you want to add an additional `2x` to the objective, you can just do this:

```py
model.obj += 2*model.x
```

If you inspect the objective using `model.obj.pprint()` you will see that it changed as expected:

```
obj : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
    Key  : Active : Sense    : Expression
    None :   True : minimize : x + 2*x
```

(although the terms are not collected, but that's the normal Pyomo behaviour, when initializing the objective initially as well)

For completeness, note that can modify the objective directly also in other ways. For example, you can change the sense:

```py
model.obj.sense = pyo.maximize
```